# how to understand table fields in a table?

Tags: lua

```
> w={x=0, y=0, label = "console"}
> print(w[x])
nil
> print(w.x)
0
> print(w["x"])
0
>
```

Hi, I was wondering, why does print(w["x"]) give a 0, while print(w[x]) gives nil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because x and "x" are two different things.

`x` is a nil-value and `"x"` is a string.

`print(w[x])` is equivalent to `print(w[nil])` in your code.

```
 w={x=0, y=0, label = "console"}
```

is syntantic sugar for

```
w={["x"]=0, ["y"]=0, ["label"] = "console"}
```

So `{x=0}` actually stores `0` under the key `"x"`.

From [Lua Reference Manual 2.1 Values and Types](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1):

> The type table implements associative arrays, that is, arrays that **can**
>   **have as indices not only numbers, but any Lua value except nil** and
>   NaN. (Not a Number is a special value used to represent undefined or
>   unrepresentable numerical results, such as 0/0.) Tables can be
>   heterogeneous; that is, they can contain values of all types (except
>   nil). **Any key with value nil is not considered part of the table.**
>   **Conversely, any key that is not part of a table has an associated**
>   **value nil.**

Comment: But in w={x=0, y =0, label = "console"}, I have already have a key, value pair (x,0).

Comment: @kkxx read my answer. your key value pair is ("x",0), not (x,0) you would have to write `[x]=0` but as `x` is nil this would result in an error "table index is nil". This only works if `x` is not nil or NAN

Comment: So,  you mean, x in the first line of code w={x=0,y=0,label="console"}, is a string "x", not a variable x?

Comment: I see, {x=0, y=0} is equivalent to {"x"=0, "y"=0} in table constructors.

Comment: @kkxx yes. please read the Lua manual befor you do anything else!